# Custom account type for secondary user in Android N

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-7.0-nougat, android-account, android-authenticator

My application provides a [custom account type](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html), which can be created via

`Preferences->Accounts->Add account`

Everything works as expected. However, when I change to a non-primary user, my custom user account is not on the list, so I cannot create one.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: Tested on Android 7.1.2 (Google Pixel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how, but the problem has gone...